# Dedicated server vs combined client-server?

Tags: multithreading, networking, scalability

I'm writing a game server and clients. The server generates a world and serves that up to various player clients. It is not massively multiplayer.

The client (at least for now) runs a fairly demanding software renderer, as well as doing the standard client side simulation (which is then subject to approval by the authoritative server), so any processing scalability available on this end would be good.

The server will also be processor intensive, and given the nature of the project, is likely to only become more so as the project progresses. The world is procedural and some of that happens *during* play; world options are set before a game begins, based on system capabilities at that time (ideally with minimal outside processes running). So scalability on the number of hardware threads is an absolute necessity for the server.

Again, as this is *not an MMO*, players will all have access to both client and server, so that they can set up their own servers. Many players will have only one machine on which to both host a server, and run the client, in order to be able to play with their friends. Based on this fact, which would serve me better?

- A combined client and server process
- Separate client and server processes

...And why?

PS. Even if some of the above complexity only comes to pass later, I need to get the architecture (in this regard) right, as early on as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the most important aspect to help you with decision is - are there any computation intensive tasks that are shared for both client and server? If you can do some computation for both client and server once instead of twice, then it makes sense to have one process (but this may be quite hard to implement). Otherwise i say separate it.

I see few advantages with separated processes:

- when client crashes (i'd say more probable with complicated renderers and/or buggy graphics drivers) server stays up
- accidentally(and/or angry QQ) exiting game won't kill the game for other players
- (if needed) it's easier to bind server to few cores and client to others
- you probably need to write dedicated server anyway (so it can be hosted on remote servers, possibly without graphics) and porting it to other OSes might be easier ...
- makes the client code overall less complicated

(i may later add something to the list if i come up with it)

Comment: I find your points 1 to 3 particularly insightful, thank you for these. As for 4, that's not strictly true; one can write a server with an embedded client, and simply turn off the client aspect. As for 5, potentially, but of course there will be duplicated logic between client and server as you suggest at the beginning of your post. You don't address client-vs-server throttling when running both on the same box, however. The only thing really preventing me from going pure client-server is this concern.

Comment: Well what I was trying to suggest at the beginning was not just de-duplicating the code, but rather removing actual execution redundancy. Meaning, if both, client and server, have to do something - ie. some physics computation - and you can share the results between client and server, then it makes sense to have them in one process and share the results. But efficiency of this depends mainly on how much work can be shared and how difficult is it to implement the sharing.

Comment: The problem with that, I realised, is that the server is authoritative, so really I cannot combine that logic without putting server security at some level of risk. Yet another pointer toward pure client server.

Comment: What security issue do you have in mind? As long as user is in control of the server, he can abuse it in both cases. And if server is doing more rigorous calculations than client, you still may be able to use server's results.

Comment: "when client crashes..." <- This. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns is always an important factor, so it's better to keep them as separate processes. It's also better for performance. If I only want to use the client functionality, there is no reason to also keep the server-related code in the same application. I will only launch it if I need it.

Comment: How would you propose to manage a server simulation running at high demand, while at the same time running a client on that same box? Bearing in mind that the server settings are set in the game lobby before it begins, and won't be changeable at runtime? I think that with a combined client-server app, there is better overall control, since we can minimise competition for threads and prioritise the server over the client.

Comment: Well it depends how high this demand is. A standard desktop PC has a pretty limited ability to serve clients. Don't expect to connect more than 3-4 clients in addition to the one running on the same machine. A simple PC just doesn't have the necessary resources for this.

Comment: Hmm. I find that highly subjective. That's the whole point of my discussing scalability... at design time, you actually don't know what the user will have. Total Annihilation was a very good example of a scalable server that was in use many years beyond what the designers realistically foresaw. That scalability served it very, very well over more than a decade.

Comment: @Nick Wiggill: regarding the priority, you can also start separate processes (Client and Server) with higher or lower priority, not just threads. In my opinion, it is very error-prone to manage the combined threads together.

Comment: That's true. I've not done that before, so I guess I should look into it. I'm just a bit concerned about potential pitfalls with that. Particularly, I would think the degree of granularity in a combined  threadpool is going to offer better efficiency than process-based prioritisation. This is just speculation, though.

Comment: The problem I would see with using a combined pool is that if you take some of the threads from the pool to do I/O operations for the server and they block waiting for input, you are restricting the client because it has less threads to work with (since the pool threads are unusable due to the I/O). Keeping separate processes will ensure that such interference is not possible.

Comment: A fair point. Yet another approach: What do you think about allowing the user to limit client and server to a fixed number of threads each, via a pre-runtime dialog or command line option? So with 8 hardware threads available, you might specify 5 for the server and 3 for the client, and within their own processes they cannot exceed these pool sizes. I wonder if there are any major pitfalls to this approach. One I can see straightaway is this might be problematic on machines with only 1 or 2 hardware threads. Then again, those are rare enough nowadays.

Comment: @Nick Wiggill: This would assume that anyone using the application is versed in threading and knows exactly how you implemented the application such that they can optimally tune the performance. Is this really the case?

Comment: Indeed, that wouldn't work at all. I think the most important thing here is that server processing must not be interfered with at any cost. I'll look into this process prioritisation -- thanks.